# Change "Read More" button link on Out of stock Woocommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

Is it possible to change the Read More button of a out of stock product to redirect to a specific page/url or popup message instead of going to the single product view.

Whenever I have an out of stock product id like to have a popup message appear saying something in a Lightbox window.

Comment: A change of attack is is possible to add another button to the archive page for out of stock items only and have the direct to a lightbox popup or another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will change the product button link when product is out of stock on Woocommerce archive pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'out_of_stock_read_more_url', 50, 2 );
function out_of_stock_read_more_url( $link, $product  ) {
    // Only for "Out of stock" products
    if( $product->get_stock_status() == 'outofstock' ){

        // Here below we change the link
        $link = home_url("/custom-page/");
    }
    return $link;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that. Is it possible to change the read more text to say Order or ETA instead. And if possible display a different colour than my theme displays. Current my buttons are blue with white text. Could i have the out of stock items have red with white text

Comment: This code works perfectly in redirecting out of stock items to a new url. However is it possible launch a popup window via shortcode. Ive created a simple popup window with Themify Popup however to load popup from a button requires a shortcode which the plugin generates

Comment: The following shortcode is used to open my popup 
[tf_popup link="62343"]Launch Popup[/tf_popup]. 
Id like to use in the above shortcode to open on the following command
  // Here below we change the link
        $link = home_url("/custom-page/");
Is this possible

Comment: LoicTheAztec are u able to help with my followup question